# Use variable for generic type when creating new instance

Tags: java, generics

I am trying to do something, and it may not be the best way to go about it, or maybe I'm just missing something in the language design. Basically, I have some service that looks like this:

```
public class MyService<T extends MyAbstractClass>{}
```

As a configuration to my server, I want to dictate which extension of `MyAbstractClass` I use as an environment variable. In my specific use case, it's basically setting up a specific datasource for what I'm doing, but that isn't too important here.

I thought I may be able to do something like this, but it is giving me syntax errors, so it's obviously not allowed. I am not sure if I can do what I am trying to accomplish.

```
@Bean(name="myService")
public MyService<? extends MyAbstractClass> getMyService(){
    String packageName = "com.my.project." + ConfigUtils.get(env, "mypackage") + "";
    Class<? extends MyAbstractClass> clazz = (Class<? extends MyAbstractClass>) Class.forName(packageName);
    return new MyService<clazz>();
}
```

I have looked around for an answer, but I'm not even sure how to phrase this properly in a search engine to find it. How should I be trying to accomplish this in java?

Comment: Are you comfortable with the idea that MyService<Foo> and MyService<Bar> are indistinguishable at runtime?

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth Yes I am, but it's a complaint I continually run into with java, so probably some part of me boneheadedly refuses to accept it. I am trying to make everything nice and neat so I only need to extend that MyAbstractClass without adding other code or unecessary conditionals around.

Comment: One way to think about it is to consider whether the wildcard has any advantage over simply MyService<MyAbstractClass> in this context.

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth Ah yes, of course. It would really make more sense in this case to not even parameterise my class at all, and instead pass in an instance of whatever abstract class I need to use within it on construction.

Answer (score 1):

This will never work:

```
new MyService<clazz>()
```

where `clazz` is a variable.

The type parameters in a `new` invocation can only be another type parameter of the enclosing method or class (if the enclosing method is not static) or a concrete class name.

Type parameters are entities that only have an impact in compilation time, introduced in order restrict the type of parameter and return values in generic classes and methods and fail at compilation time if the code would be potentially passing a value of the wrong type in run-time.

The value of `clazz` can only be determined at run-time so there is no way that the compiler can figure what the actual class is at compilation time. So that is why this is not legal nor makes any sense to use Class reference containing variables as type parameter arguments.

The truth is that it is rather impossible to restrict what the returned MyService instance's underlying type-parameter is and to return 
`MyService<? extends MyAbstractClass>` is as good as it gets.

At the very least you can double check that the `clazz` in fact extends MyAbstractService instead of simply believe blindly that is the case:

```
class ServiceClass {}
class MyService<T extends ServiceClass> {}

class Main {

   public MyService<? extends ServiceClass> getMyService() throws Exception {
      final String className = "com.my.project." + ConfigUtils.get(env, "mypackage");
      @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
      final Class<? extends ServiceClass> clazz = (Class<? extends ServiceClass>) Class.forName(className);
      if (!ServiceClass.class.isAssignableFrom(clazz))
         throw new RuntimeException("bad configuration blah blah");
      return new MyService<ServiceClass>();
   }
}
```

Notice that `new MyService<ServiceClass>()` does not seem very neat as in fact `clazz` will normally be something else; a descendant of ServiceClass but not ServiceClass itself... the reason that this compiles without errors is that given the code so far, it is irrelevant what type-parameter you return as in run-time they are all translated into the same code.

However in a more complex context when you want to perform some operations with objects that some how make reference to the same type-parameter you will start bumping into compilation time issues. Thus is always advisable to using a more neat type-parameter based solution from the on-set:

```
class ServiceClass {}
class MyService<T extends ServiceClass> {}

class Main {

   public <S extends ServiceClass> MyService<S> getMyService() throws Exception {
      final String className = "com.my.project." + ConfigUtils.get(env, "mypackage");
      @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
      final Class<S> clazz = (Class<S>) Class.forName(className);
      if (!ServiceClass.class.isAssignableFrom(clazz))
         throw new RuntimeException("bad configuration blah blah");
      return new MyService<S>();
   }
}
```

Now I think it is rather strange that you wouldn't need to keep a reference to the service class somewhere in MyService... perhaps you eventually would need to code something like the following:

```
class ServiceClass {}

class MyService<S extends ServiceClass> {
  private final Class<S> clazz;
  MyService(Class<S> clazz) {
     this.clazz = clazz;
  }

  Class<S> serviceClass() {
    return clazz;
  }
}

class Main {
  public <S extends ServiceClass> MyService<S> getMyService() throws Exception {
    final String className = "com.my.project." + ConfigUtils.get(env, "mypackage");
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    final Class<S> clazz = (Class<S>) Class.forName(className);
    if (!ServiceClass.class.isAssignableFrom(clazz))
       throw new RuntimeException("bad configuration blah blah");
    return new MyService<S>(clazz);
  }
}
```

At this point the type-parameter `S` in `getMyService` starts to be kind of necessary.

By the way since Java 7 (I think) you don't need to specify the `S` in the new statement, that will be deduced by the compiler:

```
return new MyService<>(clazz);
```

Answer (score -1):

You cannot use a wildcard in method declaration. Instead use another type variable and declare it.

```
public <S extends MyAbstractClass> S getMyService() {
    // implementation omitted
}
```

Remember that `S` in this case is not the same as `T` from the class declaration. That's why I usually give them different names.

In the method body you can then use something like:

```
Class<S> clazz = (Class<S>)Class.forName(packageName);
return clazz.newInstance();
```

Comment: Where does the concrete value for S come from?

Comment: It's a definition for the scope of this method. Something like: "There's the type `S` that is some subtype of `MyAbstractClass` and I will use it in this method." It's just the same as declaring a generic type to a class, but here it's declared for a method scope.

Comment: What i mean is, how will it be parameterised? In the OP's code, the concrete type is only known at runtime.

Comment: You can write something like `MyService<? extends MyAbstractClass> result = getMyService()`. There's no need to know the concrete type here.

Comment: But in which case, there's no need for `S extends`.